Restriction rule not working
I have a custom object "customObject" with OWD public read/write.
I need certain users to access certain records of this such object.
I created fields:
User.ConfidentialAccess -- checkbox.
customObject.Confidential -- checkbox.
And I created an active restriction rule:
User.ConfidentialAccess = true
customObject.Confidential = true
Is there anything wrong with this definition? Am I misunderstanding the concept of restriction rules?
(EDIT) Thank you, Callum: I am adding the behavior resulting after activating the restriction rule: all users see all records... and this is why I say the restriction rule is not working.
I need the user with the ConfidentialAccess checkbox = true to be able to access the record with the Confidential checkbox = true.
On the other hand, the user with ConfidentialAccess = false to be able to access any records EXCEPT the records with Confidential = true.
Thx!

Hi, it would be great to understand what you mean by 'not working'. I'm assuming that it means that users with the ConfidentialAccess = true can't see records?

I just edited the question. I need user.ConfidentialAccess=false to be UNABLE to access records with confidential=true.

That does look like it should be working, it almost fits the scenario for using custom fields detailed here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_restriction_rule_examples.htm&type=5. The only consideration would be checking that there isn't another Restriction Rule evaluating to true for the same users.

Actually, that's the first restriction rule I created... ChatGPT said I should review the "Modify all data" and "View all data" values in the object OWD (and any permission sets)... I'm checking on that too.

Do User.ConfidentialAccess = false
customObject.Confidential = false
It will work for sure
As we are restricting we do restricting non confidential users to non confidential records

Actually, I tried and it did. It's all math. The proper answer was to restrict false "confidential" records to false "confidential access" users
